# Better way to initialize an array in initialization list

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list

so lets suppose i have this structure

```
struct CAddition {
    int x;
    int y;
    int c;
    int z[3];
    int result() { 
        return x + y; 
    }
    CAddition();
    ~CAddition();
};
CAddition::CAddition()
    :x(0)
    ,y(2)
    ,z()
    ,c(result())
{

}
```

and now in the constructor I have initialized z which is an array member of the struct     `,z()` it output the initialized values with zeros , now when I try this other syntax

```
,z{}
```

and

```
,z{0,0,0}
```

they all output the same result 
Is there a more efficient way to initialize an array in the constructor except the above two and is there any difference the 3 methods , I checked different websites for initialization they have used the either methods

Comment: set the values with z[...]

Comment: You're asking if there is a "better" way. For this, you need to define what constitutes "good/bad" for you. *How* should the other method be better, what are the listed ones lacking, etc.?

Comment: by better I mean more efficient, as arrays are memory allocation

Comment: *"array are memory allocation"* - I don't understand what you mean by that. You have an array with automatic storage duration, so what allocation are you worried about?

Comment: @KillzoneKid read the question again sir! that is my question if I could answer that I wouldn't have posted it

Comment: An array with dynamic memory allocation would be a pointer. And you should prefer `std::vector` over that anyway (which works with initializer lists)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize all elements in array with default value 0, using z{0} is very fast. Or if you want to initialize with the value -1, you can use memset() :

```
CAddition::CAddition()
:x(0)
,y(2)
,c(result())
{
   memset(z, -1, 3 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Notice that, memset() works on bytes, not the number. If you need to fill array with a number , you can use fill_n() instead.

Answer (score 0):

If by "more efficient way" you mean taking less time to construct `CAddition`, then no there isn't.

The fastest way to construct `CAddition` is to initialize the array to all zeros, which is the default behaviors.

It will take negligible amount of time for an array of 3 items, but it can take a long time if the size of the array is very large, in which case you'd be better off using `std::vector` and `reserve` some space instead.